# No query results for model [App\Group]. (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2.I am getting following 2  errors when I goto my route:

error 1:

> NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 103:
>
> No query results for model [App\Group].

error 2:

> ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 209:
>
> No query results for model [App\Group].

my routes:

```
Route::get('/groups/create/', [
    'uses'=>'GroupController@creategroup',
    'as'=>'creategroup'
    ]);

Route::post('/groups/create/', [
    'uses'=>'GroupController@newgroup',
    'as'=>'newgroup'
    ]);
```

my controller:

```
public function creategroup(){
        return view('creategroup');
    }

public function newgroup(Request $request){

           $this->validate($request, [
             'groupname'=>'required|min:5',
         ]);

      $group=new Group();
      $group->name=$request['groupname'];
      $group->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
      $group->save();

      

       
     $users = DB::table('groups')
            ->join('group_user', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
            ->where('group_user.user_id',Auth::user()->id)
            ->select('groups.*')
            ;

$groups = DB::table('groups')
            ->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
            ->select('*')
            ->unionAll($users)
            ->get();

            

    return view('mygroups',['groups'=>$groups]);      
        
    }
```

Comment: Before using the model in the controller, you have to use it with 'use' keyword in beginning of your controller.
like this : use App\Group;

Comment: @KumarRaviSingh actually its already there. :(

Comment: have you changed the model name by renaming the model_file.php?
in this case, you need to update the class name also.

Comment: @KumarRaviSingh sry didnt get you...my model file name is Group.php

Comment: It was for if you change your model name by updating the php file. Seems you haven't done that. :)

Comment: Sometimes Laravel gets confused by keywords used in its library and keywords defined bu users. The group might already be a pre-defined keyword as in SQL query schema, try changing the model name.

Comment: @KumarRaviSingh changed the name to 'Grp'....still getting the error:No query results for model [App\Grp].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126377/discussion-between-kumar-ravi-singh-and-yash-chaudhary).

Comment: Which `Route` do you get this error with? Laravel, would only throw this error if you're using `findOrFail` or `firstOrFail` (To my knowledge). Neither your routes nor your controller methods are trying to load these up.

Comment: Is there a data in Group table? If yes, then try changing user id or try accessing the existing data